# Apply display:none; to unselected elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have several divs. One of them has `class="active"`. I want all the divs to be hidden (`display:none;`) except the one with `.active`. What should the selector be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
div { display: none; }

div.active { display: block; }
```

PS. I'll add explanation. When you specify a class in a selector it has higher priority in cascading logic (because of its higher [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity)) than just a single div (because single div is more generic, wider). So there is no need to use `!important` or stuff like that.

Comment: I was trying to use the `:not`, but this is better I think. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try the [`:not` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/%3anot).

For example:

```
div:not(.active) {display:none;}
```

As Paul commented below, this selector is not supported in IE8 and below. But considering you included the `CSS3` tag and specifically asked for a *selector*, that might not be an issue. For a cross-browser solution, see @mkdotam answer.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite True. Added a note about that.

Comment: Ooh it is tagged css3 isn't it, I hadn't spotted that.

Answer (score 1):

```
div:not(.active){
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

use `!important` in with css, something like that:

```
.active {
    display: block !important;
}
```

and example: http://jsfiddle.net/hNLen/

Comment: I mean, especially when [your code works just fine *without* `!important`](http://jsfiddle.net/hNLen/1/).